# Smart completion for javascript

Tags: emacs, code-completion, cedet

I ve just started to use `Emacs`. What I want to get is a kind of smart completion for `javasacript`. Not meaning just auto-complete ( which completes words I used on previous line ).

For example, if I write `document.` or `Math.` it should show me all possible/available functions which are built-in.

I think there is some plugin called `cedet`, though I am not sure if it does this for `Javascript`. If it does support that, I couldn't make it yet. Here is what I get in my `init.el` :

```
(semantic-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/ia)
(require 'semantic/db)

(semantic-ia-show-doc 1)
(semantic-ia-show-summary 1)
(semantic-ia-describe-class 1)
(global-semantic-highlight-func-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight-mode 1)
```

and this is all `init.el` file before cedet confs: http://paste.lisp.org/display/139255

Comment: Take a look at http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#emacs

Comment: @abo-abo: you should post that as a real reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution abo-abo mentioned in the comments was [ternjs](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#emacs).

(abo-abo: if you post your response as a real reply, I'll delete this answer)

Comment: i am accepting this answer now. if you delete this after @abo-abo post his answer i will do the same for his answer. thanks.

Comment: Good plan; thanks.  Hopefully he'll respond as he deserves the credit.

Comment: cool, i have seen what it's supposed to do, but how to i set it up, the documentation for emacs on the above link isn't very clear, esp. for someone who has never used emacs like me.

Comment: on the terns link you provided, instructions are not clear. Esp. number 3. how do i let Emacs aware of terns?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, everybody (and their mom) use [LSP](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/).